# Visual Studio C++ Solution in Maven2

Tags: visual-studio, maven-2, projects-and-solutions

A new project is coming up that will require interaction between Java and C++.  It's been decided that the project will be built via Maven2.

Unfortunately I don't know anything about Maven and the Java guys don't know anything about C++.

They have their build chain all set up with various reports being emitted for each part related to CheckStyle, Findbugs, Corbortura(?) etc. and they want the same to be done with the C++ side.

Currently we have 4 apps that need building: 2 services, a tray app and a simple dialog based application. I've been told I need to have a pom for each and configure each to output to a target directory, have the tool chain produce the reports - the most particular being the code coverage which the client wants 100%.

I have sourced the tools - Bullseye and QA-C++ and requested eval copies - but I am dismayed to find there is very little information on C++ & Maven, and what little there is seems to be horror stories.

**Does anyone on SO have a good story about it (or have link to blog post)?**

**Is there a simple explanation anywhere for configuring a Visual Studio solution (preferably C++) to be Mavenized?**

I am expecting pain but I am getting increasingly wary of this venture - but unfortunately the project manager is Java side and seems hell-bent on Mavenizing it.

Comment: "Corbortura" is supposed to be "Cobertura" I guess. It is a Java code coverage tool (http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Yeah, I just typed it as I remembered hearing it from the meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following stack over flow on the topic.

[Using Maven for C/C++ projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541771/using-maven-for-c-c-projects)

Hope it helps