# What is the C++/autoconf equivalent to requirements.txt for documenting library requirements?

Tags: c++, autotools

I have a C++ library that uses autoconf that I have been maintaining for 15 years. I'm now getting it to run with CI and have discovered that I need to do a better job documenting its requirements. With a python program I do this using a file called `requirements.txt` which is used by setuptools during packaging, and I can also use in the CI system. What's the right way to document this in a C++ autotools package?

Comment: `requirements.txt` used to install required packages in python in order to build/run code.
For C++ we can achieve this like `git clone --recursive`?

Comment: I can't put a `git clone` in an autoconf file. I know that `requirements.txt` is used for Python. I want to know how to document requirements for a C++ package.

Comment: There are several C++ package managers.  [Conan](https://conan.io/) and [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/) are popular examples.

Comment: Found some useful source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cCQHJ-cNHY

Comment: autotools does not have package management functionality. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866965/does-c-have-a-package-manager-like-npm-pip-gem-etc) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for a package manager; I'm looking for a way of documenting requirements.

Comment: Neither the C++ (or C) nor the Autotools ecosystems have specific conventions for the kind of documentation you describe.  Certainly not anything intended to be machine-actionable.  I guess I would normally expect to find a README file in the source distribution that included any third-party requirements among possibly many other details.  As other comments suggest, *formalization* of these kinds of requirements is usually a feature associated with a package-management system, which the Autotools are not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of question that tech writers would want to know: What packages or dependencies are there of our product.

There's two kinds of dependency in C/C++ as opposed to a singular list of Python dependency (I'm not talking test-specific dependency found in some Python packages or that kind of sort).

There are:

- header include dependency
- library dependency

## Header Include Dependency

There is a C/C++ compiler option that list out all non-system include files:

```sh
gcc -c -MMD  <source.c>
```

For all include files:

```sh
gcc -c -MD <source.c>
```

And with those list of include files, you can find out the packages that provides it, for example, in Debian:

```sh
dpkg-query -S <include-file.h>
```

## Library Dependencies

Best approach to securing a complete list of libraries used for a particular platform/distro is to use the `ldd` to extract a list of external object codes that your program requires before it can get up and running.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# List Debian packages that a given executable is dependent on
BINARY_FILE=$1

LIB_LIST=$(ldd $1 | gawk '{ print $1 }' | tr '\n' ' ')

for THIS_LIB in $LIB_LIST; do
  dpkg-query -S $THIS_LIB
done
```

Output result of `/bin/ls` gives you a multi-platform list of packages that `ls` executable file depends on:

```
~/bin/dpkg-dependency-by-executable.sh /bin/ls
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *linux-vdso.so.1*
libselinux1:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
libc6-x32: /libx32/libc.so.6
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libc6-i386: /lib32/libc.so.6
libpcre3:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
libpcre3:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
libc6-i386: /lib32/libdl.so.2
libc6-x32: /libx32/libdl.so.2
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libc6:amd64: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6-i386: /lib32/libpthread.so.0
libc6-x32: /libx32/libpthread.so.0
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
root#
```

With those list, you can ascertain that your `autotools` has properly make dependency test for them (and often without the system-related ones).

Comment: This is useful advice in a general sense, but only tangentially related to the question actually posed.  In particular, it is of no (direct) help with respect to the OP's interest in engaging a CI system.  In the context of these remarks, the question might be construed as asking about what do with the dependency information once it has been gathered.

Comment: Ouch.  I had described a process for CD system as in Continuous Development?

Comment: You have described mechanisms for *discovering* a program's dependencies. The OP is asking for a standardized or widely supported conventional mechanism for *representing* those in machine actionable form, such as a CI system could read and work with.

Comment: Short of an IDE with excellent autoheader feature during typing of function calls, we would need to extract that functionality into a standalone tool.

Comment: In rereading the question, section “Library Dependencies” in my original answer of using `ldd` should make quick work of such library dependency listing, no?

Comment: Again, the question is not for a *mechanism* to finding the dependencies or list them.  Rather, it asks about a *standard convention* for the location and format of the resulting dependency list.

Comment: Would you be talking about /usr[/local]/include and /usr[/local]/lib[32|64] and any other placements?

Comment: The question asks for a C++ / Autotools analog to the file `requirements.txt` consumed by (Python) setuptools when composing a package distribution file.  This is a file (i) created by the software author and distributed with the package, that (ii) lists other Python packages it depends upon, (iii) in a structured format that is both human- and machine-readable.  As I commented on the question itself back when it was first posed, ***there is no such thing*** in the C++ and / or Autotools world.  Not as a standard or widely recognized convention, at any rate.