# How is Maven's support for other languages, as well as writing plugins to support other languages?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I recently asked about a [maven like tool for other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381802/is-there-any-maven-like-tool-that-works-for-many-languages) but there hasn't been any responses (except for a few upvotes :). Given that, I've decided that maybe using Maven is good, but I'd have to write my own plugins to do simple things

This gives rise to a number of issues, and I'd like to hear about solutions that people are using in their daily process:

- running other build/release systems and mostly use Maven for packaging/dependency management? (msbuild, vcbuild, cmake, setuptools)
- working directly with other languages:

  - The [native-archive-plugin](http://java.freehep.org/freehep-nar-plugin/intro.html) supports C/C++, but does it integrate with visual studio?
  - Are there other plugins for more langugages, that I've missed?
- how hard is it to write your own plugin for this?

**Question:**

What is your recommended approach for managing non-Java languages and artefacts with Maven?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currenctly using maven-scala-plugin and it work just great. I only put my sources to src/main/scala instead of java and bind scala:compile goal to compile phase and that's it. But scala is very close to java, so the issues with c++ might arise.

Comment: Scala is not only close to Java, it runs on the same infrastructure (the JVM), so it's mostly "just another Java". Jython and Groovy would be similar it that sense. Nevertheless, I'll take a look at the plugin. Thanks!