# Is there C++ project manager like NPM?

Tags: c++, open-source, project-management

I used to have NPM to manage my javascript project like `npm init` command or etc. but I'm curious about there's a C/C++ open source project manager that manage like NPM. If there is, what's name of C++ project manager?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866965/does-c-have-a-package-manager-like-npm-pip-gem-etc/30847095#30847095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake is a good project build management tool, but it does not have the dependency management capabilityies NPM or Maven have. You can check out [CPM](https://github.com/iauns/cpm), but it is not actively maintained anymore.

The [Maven Nar Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541771/using-maven-for-c-c-projects) for C/C++ projects is another option, but sadly its not very active either. See also the suggestions in the answer to a [similar question regarding Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136065/maven-like-dependency-management-for-c).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Most of C++ open source projects is using CMake? I want to design my project like most projects.

Comment: @TerNer I think CMake and autotools are the most common, I like CMake better

Comment: I used maven Nar plugin and it works quite well. I can have it compile and publish the endstates automatically (for AIX, Linux and Windows etc..) using jenkins. Maven has lot of third party integration which comes in handy as well. Only down side is, maven does not do good in a mono repo scenario.